# Java - Bukkit / Spigot *How I can make my plugin need a password to start and run?*

Tags: java, bukkit

How I can make my plugin need a password to start and run?

For example:
 When the server is active after three seconds leaves a message on console for input of the secret key (Let this be within the code).
If the secret key is not placed in a minute the server is stopped, however if the password is correct or loaded the plugin work properly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is achievable but not really in this way as you can't really register or execute commands while the server is starting up. The best option would probably be to create a config value like `authentication-key`. Then in the `onLoad()` method of your main plugin class you can check if the key in the config is valid. If its not then you can do `System.exit(1)` to kill the server. It's quite possible that forcibly killing the server could break stuff though, so I would recommend calling the built in stop command with `Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "stop");` which will stop the server once it has fully loaded up.

The cleanest way to do this would probably just be to not load your plugin though, and that way would prevent many other potential conflicts with other things. To do this you could simply not run any of the startup code unless the authentication key is valid, or you could actually disable your plugin with   `Bukkit.getPluginManager().disablePlugin(<PLUGIN INSTANCE>);`